# Why do I get "unused variable" warnings for a used variable in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

This is my class:

```
private class Node {
    public int[] pivot;
    public int pivotIndex;
}
```

I get warning in Eclipse that pivotIndex is not used, but
that is not true, it is used later in the code in the same file.
Is this a bug in Eclipse?

Comment: downvoted, because code where it is supposed to be used is not shown

Comment: I very much doubt that it's a bug in Eclipse. If you could show a *full* class which demonstrates this supposed bug, that would help. (Aside: don't use public variables.)

Comment: I suspect strongly that you have a subtle error in your code, and Eclipse is actually quite right

Comment: Rule of thumb: compilers and IDEs *do* have bug, but for each case where you wonder, it's **much** more likely that it's right and you have the problem. In all the times I ever wondered if the bug was in the compiler, I think just 3 or 4 times it was actually there. The ~1000 other times it was my mistake.

Comment: My guesstimate is that you have a local variable or parameter with the same name and you only access that and never the field.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just the fact that your variable is **mentioned** elsewhere doesn't mean it is **used**. To demonstrate:

```
public class Test {
  public void x() {
    Node n = new Node();
    n.pivot = null;
    n.pivotIndex = 0;
  }
  private class Node {
    public int[] pivot;
    public int pivotIndex;
  }
}
```

Now both `pivot` and `pivotIndex` are marked as unused, and quite justified: the program never needs their value.

Answer (score 3):

Another instance of where a variable could be mentioned but not necessarily used would be inside of any loop or if statement in a method.

```
public void method(){
  int[] pivot;
  int pivotIndex;

  ... 

  for(int i=0; i<pivot.length; i++){
     pivotIndex=i;
  }
}
```

In this example, pivot would be marked as used because this loop's condition will always be checked at least once. However in the case that the length of the array is <= 0, the loop won't be executed and therefore pivotIndex won't be seen.

Basically if there is a chance that the code won't enter the code block where a variable is mentioned, then it'll be marked as unread. Eclipse's warnings should be considered like any spell check: If you are sure it's right and it says you are wrong then in the algorithm, checking this particular case was simply overlooked or pointless to implement.